# Is this end card fan drawn, or from the manga or anime?

Tags: all-out

[Episode 4 of *All Out!!*](http://www.crunchyroll.com/all-out/episode-4-what-should-i-do-721787) closes with the following end card, on screen for 10 seconds beginning @23:50

[image: greyscale drawing from end of ep.4 of All Out!!]

It appears to be a signed image, and my assumption is that neither the mangaka nor the animation staff drew it. This looks like fan art to me, something they might have found at [Deviant Art](http://www.deviantart.com/) and got permission to use.

I know the high school rugby players of the series tend to be very muscular in the body-building sense. This drawing, though, seems to overdo it.  Their pecs are more reminiscent of a women's breasts than male anatomy. In the other sports anime I have seen, *Haikyuu!*, *Free!*, and *Yuri on Ice*, the athletes are well-developed, but lither. I can't tell if this image was drawn by a muscle fetishist or just someone who had not yet mastered anatomy.

Checking episodes 1-3, I see they all also have 10-second end cards, drawn in a different style than the anime. The episode 1 end card is another grey-scale image signed by the same person. The pecs are not as exaggerated, though. (I assume that Japanese text is a signature -- for all I know, it says, "Hi, mom!"  )

**Does anyone know if these end cards are amateur works, draft images done by the animation staff, or by the mangaka?** I like them; they give extra personality to the series. I'm curious because I don't remember seeing this sort of thing before.

Comment: FWIW, it's called "end card", and the Japanese text says 神高 (JinKou), the name of the (school) team. Regarding the real question itself, usually they are not done by their own animation staff nor mangaka. However, they might not be done by amateurs at all. [Example from Monogatari Series](https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2139201181613363101) shows they were done by artists from School Rumble, Fairy Tail, ∀Gundam, FLCL, etc...

Comment: @AkiTanaka thanks!  I edited the question, replacing "plate" with "end card". The *Monogatari* examples were cool. It sounds like the artists might be doing end cards for other series as a recreation.  Fans, but professional ones.

Comment: I just watched the first episode dubbed at Funimation.  I was surprised to see that they had eliminated the end card, and the episode is shorter, 23"41".  The Crunchyroll episodes are exactly 24 minutes, and the final 10 seconds of every episode is the end card. There is another card, too, also eliminated by Funimation. I'll call it the "after first commercial" (AFC) card.  In Japan there must be a commercial after the OP. When the episode restarts, an AFC card shows for about 9 seconds. This one is in the style of the anime. Those 2 cards account for the missing 19 secs. of a dubbed episode.